# What is the difference between File based encryption and Full disk encryption. Can someone explain in brief

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, file-system, encryption, kernel, 7.0-nougat

Can someone explain what is difference between File based encryption and Full disk encryption. I had gone through Android Developer Page but it is not clear. Can someone explain with examples.

Comment: Why -1 ? Please bother to leave comment

Answer (score 0):

File encryption encrypts the contents only.  i.e. the file name and permissions can still be seen by anyone (with appropriate permissions) and so the rest of the disk structure is also available for view.  Disk base encrypts all elements of the disk including file/directory structures including permissions, so nothing is understandable without first decrypting the disk.  Another difference is that file encryption is usually performed as a single action, each way as a whole action where as disk encryption is on the fly, i.e. only the part being accessed (i.e. sector of the disk) is decoded as its needed.
Hope that helps.